# Clarity of terms used in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, metadata, hadoop2, namenode

I have come across several terms while getting familiar to HDFS. Few of the terms are like: `namespace`, `metadata`, `transaction logs`, `fsimage`, `editlogs`.

Sometimes it appears that all these terms describe same thing, which is "having some information", but i am not clear on this.

In general `metadata` means data about data so would `metadata` refer to all these terms or all these terms have different purpose in context of Hadoop HDFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Namepace** : Within hadoop 'namespace' refers to the file names with their paths maintained by a name node.

**Metadata** : it includes the name of the file, size, permissions etc...
This metadata is stored in a file called **fsimage**.

**fsimage** : complete state of the hdfs file system at a point of time.

Any **changes** done to the **filesystem** are not written to **fsimage** immediately but there are stored in a separate file (on the same location where fsimage is stored) called **editlog**.

**editlogs:** It is a log that lists each file system change that was made after the most recent fsimage.

[image]